# POST запрос Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit

Возникла проблема при попытке создать POST запрос через retrofit по нажатию на кнопку.

```
public interface HZApi {
@POST("/registration")
public Call<RespBody> register(@Body ReqBody request);
}

public class RespBody {
String login;
String password;
boolean flag;
}

public class ReqBody {
String login;
String password;

public ReqBody(String login, String password){
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}
}

public void ClickOK(View v){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://mysite.ru")
            .build();
    HZApi api = retrofit.create(HZApi.class);
    ReqBody req = new ReqBody(login,password);
    Call<RespBody> call = api.register(req);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RespBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RespBody> call, Response<RespBody> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RespBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    ;
}
}
```

На строке

```
HZApi api = retrofit.create(HZApi.class);
```

вылетает исключение `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Добавьте полный стектрейс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `onCreate() \ onCreateView()`

Проверьте инициализацию вашей кнопки

```
findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

В onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.my_button:
            //ваш запрос
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Странно, ведь функция была описана в xml файле. Спасибо за помощь!